# Excel document vanished after edit

Tags: excel

I had an excel sheet for the past few year which I edited every week (several times per week) and had no problem with.
I last opened and edited it 3 days ago. After what I saved it and closed Excel. Now, after opening excel, it still appears in the list of recent documents BUT displays an error saying **"Sorry, we couldn't find DOCUMENT_PATH_AND_NAME. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"**

The document is no longer in the forder where it used to be and is also not in the recycle bin. A search in windows explorer found just a shortcut to the document (pointing at the folder it used to be into). I restarted the computer, used a recovery software (recuva) without much success.

It happened with Excel 365 2016 on a Windows 8.1 computer.

Any idea how to get that document back? thanks in advance for your help.

P.S.: before you talk about backups, I have a backup from early april but cannot do without the data added between that first week of april and now.

Comment: "I have a backup from early april". Well, that will teach you. (At the time of writing, I have a backup as-of 15.00 GMT today).

Comment: Is there a temporary-looking file in that folder?

Comment: Just to note for you going forward, you can do [Automatic backups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-save-a-backup-copy-of-a-workbook-9b947d35-f218-4238-be39-04668b0975eb) in Excel, there are [a few different ways](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/automatic-backups-excel) to do so.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne.
What do you mean by "temporary-looking file in that folder", Bathsheba?

Answer (score 0):

You have made the common mistake of not backing up your work, and it also seems like you have been unsuccessful in recovering your data with a recovery program. Realistically speaking, you basically have one choice.

**You will have to recreate the contents of the document starting from early April.**

If such a task is impossible, I advise you to scream into a pillow and to then make yourself a big cup of camomille tea spiked with vodka.

Best of luck